# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' error 403

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-iam

I am trying setup Google Cloud API Translate for a script
But doesn't work and after 3 hours investigating I ask you for help

the code of quickstart.php is

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use t

his file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
# [START translate_quickstart]
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'directed-radius-214010';

# Instantiates a client
$translate = new TranslateClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The text to translate
$text = 'Hello, world!';
# The target language
$target = 'fr';

# Translates some text into Russian
$translation = $translate->translate($text, [
    'target' => $target
]);

echo 'Text: ' . $text . '
Translation: ' . $translation['text'];
# [END translate_quickstart]
return $translation;
```

and error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message '{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } ' in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-docs-samples/translate/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php:265 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-docs-samples/translate/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php(170): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException)) #1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-docs-samples/translate/vendor/google/cloud-core/RestTrait.php(96): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-d in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-docs-samples/translate/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapper.php on line 265

I am setup Google Credential correctly or so I think, with putty I used

> export
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/dev/translator/php-docs-samples/translate/keysss.json"

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: `The request is missing a valid API key` ...is what it says. and your PHP code does not refer to any `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` nor import that Linux environmental variable... this has little to do with each other. simply setting the `keyFilePath` to the path to the file might be the most simple.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly due to several reasons such as missing files, invalid credential paths, incorrect environment variables assignations, among other causes. Keep in mind that when you set an environment variable value in a session, it is reset every time the session is dropped.

Based on this, I recommend you to validate that the credential file and file path are being correctly assigned, as well as follow the [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) guide, in order to explicitly specify your service account file directly into your code; In this way, you will be able to set it permanently and verify if you are passing the service credentials correctly.

**Passing the path to the service account key in code example:**

```
namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\Auth;

// Imports the Google Cloud Storage client library.
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function auth_cloud_explicit($projectId, $serviceAccountPath)
{
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    $config = [
        'keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath,
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ];
    $storage = new StorageClient($config);

    # Make an authenticated API request (listing storage buckets)
    foreach ($storage->buckets() as $bucket) {
        printf('Bucket: %s' . PHP_EOL, $bucket->name());
    }
}
```